# Mac, Stop to ask keychain password

Tags: ios, macos

I have create a bash script code with `fastlane sigh resign` code when it hit/call each time it asking for keychain passsword so is there any idea how to stop asking keychain password....

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep entering your passcode and clicking always allow. There might be anywhere from 2 to 20 popups. If you click always allow now then you wouldn't have to do it later and it would stop showing up.